# Echo update query in laravel 4.2..?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel-4.2 and i want to `echo` my query. When i googled it found `toSql()` is one of the way for it but it only work with select. But i want it with the update query.

does anyone have an idea how I may echo the update query?
or how to use `toSql()` with the update query?

Comment: You're looking for `DB::getQueryLog()` and it returns an `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your routes.php file and you will see the SQL that Eloquent is executing when you go to pages that have any sort of access to Eloquent models. This helps a lot when debugging SQL in Laravel.

```
// Display all SQL executed in Eloquent
Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
{
   var_dump($query);
});
```

OR 
Simple to use

```
 DB::getQueryLog()
```

Comment: I think DB::getQueryLog() is nice and helpfull.